# Power BI - Multiple Regions and Multiple KPI's all in one View

Tags: visualization, powerbi, kpi

I am looking for a visual in Power BI that shows a list of regions along with various KPI's all on one visual, so that I can easily compare one region to the next all in one snapshot.  In an excel report, the view would resemble list of Regions down the rows, and the various KPI's(red/green/yellow) along the columns. Is there a visual in Power Bi that represents this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Table visual for this. Each KPI would be modeled as a Measure, and added to the Values well. Conditional Formatting would be applied to each KPI to set the colors.